# using ajax call to popup jquery dialog form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link with get parameters. When I click it, ajax is called. Now when it goes to

action.php, I have a form with php values(from mysql). I want to pop this with jquery

dialog.

I am not sure how to do this.

```
      <script>


 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.href,
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){           
            if (response.length > 0) {  
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=wrapperelement; 
                wrapperelement.innerHTML = response; 
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            }
        }
 });
});
</script>
```

**updated codes**

The body of this file

```
       <body>
       <div id="display"></div>
       echo '<a href="action.php?pldid=' . $pldid . '" class="editbt">Edit</a>';
       </body>
```

So my action.php

```
   if (isset($_GET['pldid'])&& $_GET['pldid'])
 {
 $form = <<<EOF
<form>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Fields">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>



 <form>
 <fieldset>
 <label for="box">Box</label>
 <input type='text' name='box' id='box' class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
 <label for="itemname">itemname</label>
 <input type='text' name='itemname' id='itemname' class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
<label for="size">size</label>
 <input type='text' name='size' id='size' class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
<label for="potency">potency</label>
 <input type='text' name='potency' id='potency' class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
<label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
 <input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity' class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />

 </fieldset>
 </form>

</div>
EOF;
echo $form;
}
```

I want the link to open up a window with form(values from mysql). Any suggestion is highly welcomed..Thanks you..

Answer (score 0):

If your form is not on page yet, then `action.php` should only create the markup of the form, so on success, just append the markup via `innerHTML` method and thus show the dialog.

**script.php**

```
<?php

$form = "";
if (isset($_GET['pldid']) && $_GET['pldid']) { 
    $form = <<<EOF
<form id="dialog-form">
  ...
</form>
EOF;
}

echo $form;
?>
```

**markup / javaScript**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- I'm your wrapper. I'm waiting to receive your markup --> 
</div>

<script>
     var wrapperelement = document.getElementById('wrapper');
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(response){           
                if (response.length > 0) {   
                    wrapperelement.innerHTML = response; 
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                }
            }
     });
</script>
```

Where *wrapperelement* is an empty element in which you append the markup generated on server-side

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But the form is in the action php file.. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier...

Comment: Actual I want to pop up the window with form with php values.. Any idea..Thanks..

Comment: Thank you for that edit.. But the dialog-form div id is in action php file.. Will that pop up?? Thanks

Comment: You need the javascript that calls the popup to be in the asp page, not the originating page.

Comment: @Fabrizio wrapperelement, I cannot get this.. Should I use a div called wrapperelement in my action.php?? Thank you

Comment: Create an empty element in your page (a simple div with an id), create a reference to it with document.getElementById. This is your *wrapperelement*

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I have done the referencing part..Updated the code.. But it says wrapperelement undefined... Is the syntax correct? I pasted it from online..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(response){           
                if (response.length > 0) {   
                    wrapperelement.innerHTML = response; 
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                }
            }
     });
```

Comment: Can you explain why this will work over what the OP already has? Your code seems almost identical except for the removal of one line